# What is a javascript class exactly?

Tags: javascript

I often hear that a class `A`, defined with `class A {...}`, is just a *constructor*, but that doesn't seem to be the case since we can access the constructor as `A.constructor`. So is it the *prototype*? That doesn't seem to be the case either as `A` is different from `A.constructor.prototype`. And yet, `A` is a *function*: `A instanceof Function` evaluates to `true` and `typeof A` to `'function'`.

So what is a class exactly? A thin *wrapper* around the constructor? Can we create a class programmatically so that it's impossible to distinguish it from a class created through the `class` keyword?

Comment: Nobody says that class is a constructor. A `constructor()` method is a constructor.

Comment: Classes in javascript inherently are "special" functions. [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

Comment: @RoboRobok: A class is a constructor. There, someone said it. :)

Comment: @Ry- it's like saying that a blueprint is a factory.

Comment: Yes... it's just a thin wrapper around the conctructor Function. That's exactly what it is. However some abstractions build upon them, like [the private class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields) make them very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but that doesn't seem to be the case since we can access the constructor as `A.constructor`

`A.constructor` is the `Function` constructor (because `A` is a function), not the class’s constructor.

```js
class A {}

console.log(A.constructor === Function);
console.log(A.constructor.constructor === Function);
console.log(A.constructor.constructor.constructor === Function);
// all true, etc.

console.log(typeof A);
// function
```

What you’ve heard - that “a class … is just a constructor” – is more or less correct, though I’d leave out the “just”. A JavaScript constructor contains everything necessary to use the language’s object-oriented features; `A` is a function that acts as a constructor, and objects constructed with it have the prototype `A.prototype`.

Comment: You cleared my doubt by just saying "A.constructor is the Function constructor"! I'm new to js and forgot functions are also objects. I knew it but didn't connect the dots. Thank you! I added an answer that might be useful to someone, but accepted your answer, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I think this code speaks for itself:

```js
class A {}

a = new A();
console.log(a.__proto__.constructor === A);   // true
```